# How to resolve this error in odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Hi i am trying to install this module with pre install libraries ,https://www.odoo.com/apps?search=geoengine.
[image: After installing module its shoing this modules in my instance]

[image: But I am getting this error while installing]

Answer (score 0):

First Install

```
sudo apt-get install postgis
```

There is Python Dependency

**How to install? :**

```
sudo apt-get install python-shapely
OR
sudo pip install shapely
```

**Download :**
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely

and other Python Dependency is geojson

```
sudo pip install geojson
```

**Download :** 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geojson/

Comment: i have done samething but its showing same error since morning i m doing it